# Get second minimum values per column in 2D array

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, list, numpy

How can I get the second minimum value from each column? I have this array:

```
A = [[72 76 44 62 81 31]
     [54 36 82 71 40 45]
     [63 59 84 36 34 51]
     [58 53 59 22 77 64]
     [35 77 60 76 57 44]]
```

I wish to have output like:

```
A = [54 53 59 36 40 44]
```

Comment: second minimum _per column_?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Try this, in just one line:

```
[sorted(i)[1] for i in zip(*A)]
```

in action:

```
In [12]: A = [[72, 76, 44, 62, 81, 31], 
    ...:      [54 ,36 ,82 ,71 ,40, 45], 
    ...:      [63 ,59, 84, 36, 34 ,51], 
    ...:      [58, 53, 59, 22, 77 ,64], 
    ...:      [35 ,77, 60, 76, 57, 44]] 

In [18]: [sorted(i)[1] for i in zip(*A)]                                                                                                                                                                           
Out[18]: [54, 53, 59, 36, 40, 44]
```

> `zip(*A)` will transpose your list of list so the columns become rows.

and if you have duplicate value, for example:

```
In [19]: A = [[72, 76, 44, 62, 81, 31], 
    ...:  [54 ,36 ,82 ,71 ,40, 45], 
    ...:  [63 ,59, 84, 36, 34 ,51], 
    ...:  [35, 53, 59, 22, 77 ,64],   # 35
    ...:  [35 ,77, 50, 76, 57, 44],]  # 35
```

If you need to skip both `35`s, you can use `set()`:

```
In [29]: [sorted(list(set(i)))[1] for i in zip(*A)]                                                                                                                                                                
Out[29]: [54, 53, 50, 36, 40, 44]
```

Answer (score 8):

Operations on `numpy` arrays should be done with `numpy` functions, so look at this one:

```
np.sort(A, axis=0)[1, :]
```

```
Out[61]: array([54, 53, 59, 36, 40, 44])
```

Comment: This has to be the best solution as far as I know, it keeps everything in `numpy`, I think the `lambda` must slow down `heapq.nsmallest` solution. Seems best to keep everything fast in `numpy`

Comment: Unless you have duplicate minimum values ...

Answer (score 5):

you can use [heapq.nsmallest](https://docs.python.org/3/library/heapq.html#heapq.nsmallest)

```
from heapq import nsmallest

[nsmallest(2, e)[-1] for e in zip(*A)]
```

output:

```
[54, 53, 50, 36, 40, 44]
```

---

I added a simple benchmark to compare the performance of the different solutions already posted:

[image]

```
from simple_benchmark import BenchmarkBuilder
from heapq import nsmallest


b = BenchmarkBuilder()

@b.add_function()
def MehrdadPedramfar(A):
    return [sorted(i)[1] for i in zip(*A)]

@b.add_function()
def NicolasGervais(A):
    return np.sort(A, axis=0)[1, :]

@b.add_function()
def imcrazeegamerr(A):
    rotated = zip(*A[::-1])

    result = []
    for arr in rotated:
        # sort each 1d array from min to max
        arr = sorted(list(arr))
        # add the second minimum value to result array
        result.append(arr[1])

    return result

@b.add_function()
def Daweo(A):
    return np.apply_along_axis(lambda x:heapq.nsmallest(2,x)[-1], 0, A)

@b.add_function()       
def kederrac(A):
    return [nsmallest(2, e)[-1] for e in zip(*A)]


@b.add_arguments('Number of row/cols (A is  square matrix)')
def argument_provider():
    for exp in range(2, 18):
        size = 2**exp
        yield size, [[randint(0, 1000) for _ in range(size)] for _ in range(size)]

r = b.run()
r.plot()
```

Using `zip` with `sorted` function is the fastest solution for small 2d lists while using `zip` with `heapq.nsmallest` shows to be the best on big 2d lists

Comment: Just a wild thought: can these results be impacted by the fact that you generated numbers that are not numpy dtypes? Also, won't the built in randint return a list instead of an array?

Comment: is it the only way iterating over the rows on the np.matrix? is there a faster alternative ?

Answer (score 1):

I hope I understood your question correctly but either way here's my solution, im sure there is a more elegent way of doing this but it works

```
A = [[72,76,44,62,81,31]
 ,[54,36,82,71,40,45]
 ,[63,59,84,36,34,51]
 ,[58,53,59,22,77,64]
 ,[35,77,50,76,57,44]]

#rotate the array 90deg
rotated = zip(*A[::-1])

result = []
for arr in rotated:
    # sort each 1d array from min to max
    arr = sorted(list(arr))
    # add the second minimum value to result array
    result.append(arr[1])
print(result)
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

```py
>>> A = np.arange(30).reshape(5,6).tolist()
>>> A
[[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5], 
 [6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11], 
 [12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17], 
 [18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23],
 [24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29]]
```

**Updated**:
Use `set` to prevent from duplicate and transpose list using `zip(*A)`

```py
>>> [sorted(set(items))[1] for items in zip(*A)]
[6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11]
```

old: second minimum item in each row

```py
>>> [sorted(set(items))[1] for items in A]
[1, 7, 13, 19, 25]
```

Comment: Isn't that getting the second item in each row rather than column?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that `A` is `numpy.array` (if this holds true please consider adding `numpy` tag to your question) then you might use `apply_along_axis` for that following way:

```
import heap
import numpy as np
A = np.array([[72, 76, 44, 62, 81, 31],
              [54, 36, 82, 71, 40, 45],
              [63, 59, 84, 36, 34, 51],
              [58, 53, 59, 22, 77, 64],
              [35, 77, 60, 76, 57, 44]])
second_mins = np.apply_along_axis(lambda x:heapq.nsmallest(2,x)[-1], 0, A)
print(second_mins)  # [54 53 59 36 40 44]
```

Note that I used [heapq.nsmallest](https://docs.python.org/2/library/heapq.html#heapq.nsmallest) as it does as much sorting as required to get 2 smallest elements, unlike `sorted` which does complete sort.